# A noisy fan in a toshiba satellite C650 after Debian upgrade to Jessie

Tags: linux, laptop, debian, fan, toshiba-laptop

I search help with my *Debian Jessie* installation.
The problem is that the *cpu* fan sound is loud almost all of the time.
Before I upgrade it all the things were good with *Debian wheezy*.

I tried to solve this problem installing the 4.1 kernel from the *backports*, but I find no benefits.

I tried to solve this problem with *fancontrol* and I edited the grub files but all solutions didn't produce any benefit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax quiet splash"
```

More Details:

> Linux debian 4.1.0-0.bpo.2-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.1.6-1~bpo8+1 (2015-09-09) i686 GNU/Linux
>   .

```
masha3@debian:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +59.0°C  (crit = +114.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +51.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +52.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

.

```
    masha3@debian:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

.

```
masha3@debian:~$ glxinfo|grep render
direct rendering: Yes
   GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
   GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2
   GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp,
   GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is the fan of cpu and not the fan of the video card(always if you have that fan)?  Temperature are out of the range to make start that fan. I experienced that problem after a wrong video driver update... Good Luck.

Comment: thank you, but how to know what video driver installed, and what video driver should install.

Comment: i dont install any driver,

Comment: i dont think problem from video driver because it from intel and familiar with my driver.